# Usage of "a move" when someone is fired

Tags: word-meaning, metaphors

I quoted the following paragraphs from [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2018/sep/03/jeff-sessions-donald-trump-charges-republican-congressmen)

> Trump indicated last week that he would fire Sessions after the midterm elections, a **move** some observers said might presage the firing of deputy attorney general Rod Rosenstein and the special counsel, Robert Mueller, whose work on links between Trump aides and Moscow has circled ever closer to Trump’s inner sanctum.
>
> Some senior Republicans have indicated they would accept a **move** against Sessions, which would echo the infamous “Saturday night massacre” carried out by Richard Nixon against top law enforcement officials during his downfall in 1973. Some have said they would not.

What does "a move" mean? Does it refer that Trump fired Sessions so that Sessions had to move his position?

Comment: Have you looked up the noun **move** in an online dictionary? What did it say? Was there something confusing concerning its definition?

Comment: Anyway, check [*move*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/move): "4. *countable noun [usually singular]* - A **move** is an action that you take in order to achieve something." Being a noun, there aren't many definitions to check.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin Yes, I have already looked it up. I confused whether "a move" meant Jeff Session's "resigning" his position or Donald Trump's political action.

Answer (score 2):

A "move" is any deliberate action in a political scene. The reference is to chess.